# Back up any and all usb sticks with udev

Tags: usb-drive, udev

I have home server that I use for back up, Iv recently started using multiple shared (as in new one every few days) usb flash drives for some important files. I want to run a script to copy files only from a certain folder on the flash drive. I thought a udev rule would work great, here was what i wrote

```
KERNEL=="sd?", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTR{removable}=="1", RUN+="/home/ketterer/usb_mount.sh '%E{ID_FS_LABEL}'"
```

Then just for testing I wrote this script

```
#!/bin/bash
LABLE=$1
echo "lable is $LABLE" >> /home/ketterer/prooffile 
sleep 15
touch /media/ketterer/$LABLE/test
```

The idea is that the usb flash drive mounts under ketterer as the label, so i pass the lable to the script and then I can manipulate it, but saddly  it doesnt pass the label to the script.
any Ideas?
As funny as it is, I had it work once, I changed KERNEL=="sd?", to KERNEL=="sd?1", this made it work, but only one time and then it would not  even do the script after that

Comment: Have you checked that the folder exists? Maybe you should call `/bin/mkdir -p /media/ketterer/$LABLE` before trying to touch the file `test`

Comment: `udev` does not allow `mount` anymore, check its manpage.